# Django AssertionError - 302 is not 302

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a super simple unit test set up for an endpoint that accepts POST requests with a file, and upon successful upload redirects the user to a new page. The goal of this unit test it to ensure file uploads are working properly.

**tests.py**

```
c = Client()
with open('replays/static/test.txt', 'r', ) as f:
    response = c.post(
        '/upload/',
        {
            'summoner': 'test user',
            'title': 'Testing title',
            'replay': f
        },
        follow=False
    )

    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.status_code == 302)
    self.assertIs(response.status_code, 302)
```

**Output**

```
$ python manage.py test replays
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
302
True
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_replay (replays.tests.ReplayCreationTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/tests.py", line 52, in test_create_replay
    self.assertIs(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 302 is not 302

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.173s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

If I change the parameter for following redirects when calling the test client's post method, everything works as expected with a response_status of 200

**tests.py - follow redirect**

```
c = Client()
    with open('replays/static/test.txt', 'r', ) as f:
        response = c.post(
            '/upload/',
            {
                'summoner': 'test user',
                'title': 'Testing title',
                'replay': f
            },
            follow=True
        )

    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.status_code == 200)
    self.assertIs(response.status_code, 200)
```

**Output**

```
$ python manage.py test replays
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
200
True
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.196s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

What am I missing? It doesn't seem like this should be the expected behavior of the assertion statement. I am using Django 3.1.

Comment: @ihunter2839- Please correct me if I am wrong, in a file upload test, isn't the uploading of the actual file supposed to be mocked?

Comment: In this case, I want the file to complete upload because I am using external storages that require access keys for completion and part of the test is ensuring the keys are good. Unless there is a more effective way to accomplish that?

Comment: @ihunter2839- Seems like you are testing for 2 things. Authentication and file upload. From what I know I/O bound calls are supposed to be mocked.

Comment: Hrm, just to be clear - there is no user authentication, as the file upload is public, and the keys are for S3 buckets. If you mean application authentication, then I suppose you are correct, but I am unfamiliar with the techniques to test this uniquely.

Comment: @ihunter2839- Yeah, I meant application authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AssertIs` checks if `x is y`, in other words, that `x` and `y` refer to the *same* object. But you can have two `int` objects that are both `302`, but not the same object.

You should use [**`.AssertEqual(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual):

```
self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code)
```

For small integers, the CPython interpreter will construct int objects for -5 to 256, and thus work with a *flyweight pattern*:

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between `-5` and `256`, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

This means that for `int` between -5 and 256, it will refer to the *same* object, for values outside that range, it often constructs a new object.

Comment: I confirmed that self.assertEqual works as expected, so thank you. But I can't say I understand why self.assertIs works in the case of the status being 200 but fails when the status is 302. It seems like the behavior of the two cases *should* be the same?

Comment: @ihunter2839: because small integers (often) work with a flyweight pattern: for values up to 256 it will make a small cache with `int` objects.

Comment: @ihunter2839: see edit. However the flyweight pattern is an *implementation detail* so you should not really assume that this will (always) work, future versions can change this.